# Ogre Stereo Rendering

Tags: c++, ogre

I like to add stereo rendering for my ogre application. I found a plugin for an early version of ogre. That plugin was meant for VS 2008 and Ogre 1.6 and does not compile in my Ogre version (VS 12 + Ogre 1.9 64 bit).

http://www.ogre3d.org/forums/viewtopic.php?f=5&t=32284&start=200

I tried adding the code directly to my project but when I init the StereoManager I receive the Error "Cannot create Compositor, missing Stereomanager resource in StereoManager::initCompositor at src\StereoManager.cpp)"

Is there another way to make stereorendering in Ogre? Anyone was able to make stereorendering for 1.9 and can offer a short tutorial?

Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: You might be better off asking in the OGRE forums.

Comment: Do you get compile errors or a crash at runtime? In the first case, what are the exact errors, in the latter where exactly does it crash and what does the Ogre.log say?

Comment: I ended up inserting it via Code, the compositor error was because I forgot to copy the .material files. Nevertheless this plugin seems not to be correct. It uses only one camera, I assume it's only paralel stereo and not off-axis stereo. I am currently working on an off-axis solution.